# Change APP Icon dynamically Phonegap jQuery

Tags: jquery, cordova, dynamic, icons

is it possible to change an app icon after the app is installed? 
I'm using the Phonegap build to create the app. 
Is there also any difference between iOS and Android?

Comment: No it is not possible to change the app icon once the app is installed whether you are using phonegap or not.

Comment: Check this possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081119/android-change-app-icon-programatically

Answer (score 0):

ios (at least) does support dynamic icons like the calendar and clock so changing the icon image should be technically possible?